# How can I connect fragment in Activity?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I want to go to Fragment when Click button event. but I have issues about it.

Here's my code.

```
@OnClick(R.id.Main_Bottom_Bar_Summary)
public void onBottomBarClicked()
{
    loadFragment(new AddItemFragment());
}
private void loadFragment(android.support.v4.app.Fragment fragment) {
    FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fm.beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frameLayout, fragment);
    fragmentTransaction.commit(); // save the changes
}
```

and top of the acitivity. import files.

```
 import android.app.Fragment;
 import android.app.FragmentManager;
 import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
```

And My Fragment:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import com.and.dmt.R;

public class AddItemFragment extends Fragment 
{
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_additemdialog,container, false);}
}
```

And I can see this issue.

[image]

What's this issue? How can I solve it?

If I change loadFragment parameter "Fragment" to "android.support.v4.app.Fragment"

then This issue appear.

[image]

Comment: Are you sure you posted the same code you use in your project? Because it seems like your `loadFragment()` method expects an `android.app.fragment` instance and you pass `AddItemFragment` which extends `android.support.v4.app.Fragment`.

Comment: Check your imports . Use either v4 SupportFragment or Fragment .

Comment: See my edited answer

Answer (score 2):

`loadFragment()` takes `android.app.Fragment` as argument whereas your fragment extends `android.support.v4.app.Fragment`.

Change the argument for `loadFragment()` to take v4 Fragment and use [`getSupportFragmentManager()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentActivity.html#getSupportFragmentManager()).

Answer (score 1):

if you use support fragment, try this code :

```
 private void loadFragment(android.support.v4.app.Fragment fragment) {
        android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frameLayout, fragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit(); // save the changes
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add below code to calling Activity.

`addFragment(R.id.fragment_container, NewFragment.newInstance());`

and add below method in the fragment class which will return new Instance of that very fragment.

```
public static NewFragment newInstance() {
        return new NewFragment();
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please review [How do I write a good answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7656/how-do-i-write-a-good-answer-to-a-question).